# IS there a way to simplify this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, if-statement, variable-assignment

I am still in the "any technology sufficiently advanced..." phase of learning to program. This code seems clunky, and hard to update if needed. Is there a better way to go about this? It just looks completely bonkers to me, but it works... so yay?

It takes a variable from TKinter radial 1-16, and uses it select the grade1 ect variable. The grade1 variable then link to sheet names on gspread.

```
def go():
    subject = v.get()
    if  subject == 1:
        subject = grade1
    elif  subject == 2:
        subject = grade2    
    elif  subject == 3:
        subject = grade3
    elif  subject == 4:
        subject = grade4  
    elif  subject == 5:
        subject = grade5
    elif  subject == 6:
        subject = grade6
    elif  subject == 7:
        subject = grade7
    elif  subject == 8:
        subject = grade8
    elif  subject == 9:
        subject = grade9
    elif  subject == 10:
        subject = grade10    
    elif  subject == 11:
        subject = grade11
    elif  subject == 12:
        subject = grade12 
    elif  subject == 13:
        subject = grade13
    elif  subject == 14:
        subject = grade14
    elif  subject == 15:
        subject = grade15
    elif  subject == 16:
        subject = grade16
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not keep 16 different variables for `grade**`! Use one list:

```
grades = [1, 2, 3, ...]  # or whatever your values are
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
subject = grades[v.get() - 1]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I have done something similar with other things, but this did not clue in for me. Amazing thanks.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: whenever you attach a `…2` to any variable name, you should pause and think about what you're actually doing.

Comment: so for my TK radial buttons can I do something similar? 

    but1= Radiobutton(root,text=grade[0],padx=5, variable=v, value =1,command= go)
    but2= Radiobutton(root,text=grade[1],padx=5, variable=v, value =2,command= go)
    but3= Radiobutton(root,text=grade[2],padx=5, variable=v, value =3,command= go)

Comment: Sure… `buttons = [Radiobutton(...), Radiobutton(...), ...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining 16 separate grade1...grade16 variables, you could store them in a list like `grades=[grade1,...,grade16]` and then set subject as `subject = grades[v.get()-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Or use dictionary:

```
d={1:grade1,2:grade2 ... 16:grade16}
print(d[v.get()])
```

You will get desired grade.

You have to have a dictionary with keys of all possible `v.get()` values, and values of the grades you want for each key, so then you get the `v.get()` key in the dictionary, then get it's value, by using `d[v.get()]`, now you've got the desired grade.

Comment: is there a big difference between a list and dictionary? or is just the indexing is inside of the dictionary?

Comment: @CalvinHobbes It's actually not indexing it's getting key, then it's value, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: When iterating through a list it's `O(n)` However, a dictionary is `O(1)` because it `dictionary` uses `hash`

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to get around it.

```
# 1. Using the `list` data type
def go():
    grade_list = [grade1, grade2, ... grade16]
    subject = [grade_list[v.get() - 1]]


# 2. Using the `eval` 
def go():
       subject = v.get()
       if subject in range(1, 17):
           subject = eval("grade" + str(subject))
```

The first method is considered better code. However, there is another way of using
`eval` keyword. It treats the code inside as an expression. Since only the number part of the variable changes. However, `eval` is not the best way I recommend. For more, refer to this page [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Please don't recommend `eval` to fix a bad program/data structure.

Comment: I've edited that eval is not the best way around it :)